# Removing 4-byte UTF characters from a large file

Tags: java, bash, multibyte

I have a file containing multibyte characters. Since the file is very large and I want to remove the 4-byte utf characters from this file. I need a faster solution to do it. I tried the following java code for this task but the it gives Java heap space out of memory exception. So

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class A{
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String str=br.readLine();
  char[] c_array;
  String c_string;
  byte[] c_byte_array;
  c_array = str.toCharArray();
  for (char c : c_array){
   c_string = Character.toString(c);
   c_byte_array = c_string.getBytes("UTF-8");
   if (c_byte_array.length <= 3){
    System.out.print(c_string);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Is there any way to improve this or some other faster and better way to do it.
I also tried this grep command

```
grep -o -P "[\x10000-\x10ffff]" myfile
```

but it exits with an error

```
grep: range out of order in character class
```

So my question is what is wrong with the above regex. Or in other words what is regex to match 4-byte utf characters. 
Another question which of the above methods are more efficient to remove 4-byte characters

Comment: Ermm ... wouldn't it be better to *compress* the file?

Comment: compress the file for what? I mean I didn't get your question?

Comment: why do you want to just delete random characters from a file?  it's as odd as if you'd asked "i want to delete all lowercase letters"

Comment: Actually the file is mysqldump that I want to import in postgresql that doesn't allow one to insert 4-byte UTF characters. And the size of dump could be as large as 1-2GB. So I need a solution that is fast

Comment: @NarendraRajput - how can postgres claim to support utf-8 and not support 4-byte character sequences?  are you sure about this?

Comment: What are "UTF characters"?

Comment: The version of psotgresql I am using specifies that

Answer (score 11):

UTF-8 4-bytes characters are Unicode characters above U+FFFF (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and they are represented in Java by 2 chars. We can use Character.isSurrogate (see API) to detect such characters.

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("1.txt"), "UTF-8"));
    for (int c; (c = br.read()) != -1;) {
        if (Character.isSurrogate((char)c)) {
            // skip the second surrogate char
            br.read();
        } else {
            // process char c
        }
    }
```

or if you want to filter a byte stream then we can use another solution based on the fact  that 4-byte character UTF-8 sequence is

`11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx`

so we can filter the byte stream as

```
   BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("1.txt"));
    for (int b; (b = is.read()) != -1;) {
        if ((b & 0b11111000) == 0b11110000) {
            // skip next 3 bytes
            is.read();
            is.read();
            is.read();
        } else {
            // process byte b
        }
    }
```

Comment: Plus, your code will avoid the out of memory error since he's reading line-based, and the lines could be arbitrarily large.

Comment: I think `Character.isSupplementaryCodePoint(c)` would be more appropriate, isn't it?